# $X_n\to0$ in probability and $\{c_n\}$ is a bdd seq of real numbers, then $c_nX_n\to0$ in probability.

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose $X_n\to0$ in probability and $\{c_n\}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. Prove that $c_nX_n\to0$ in probability.

I believe I need to use a theorem, which states that:

If $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $X$ are random variables on a probability space, $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Then, $X_n\to X$ in probability as $n\to\infty$ iff every subsequence $\{X_{n_{m}}\}$ has a further subsequence $\{X_{n_{m_{k}}}\}$ such that $X_{n_{m_{k}}}\to X$ a.s. as $k\to\infty$.

I am having a difficult time formulating my thoughts though. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use that theorem to prove the result, but I think that makes it more complicated than it needs to be.

**Hint:** The typical condition of convergence in probability is:
$$X_n \stackrel{p}{\to} X \iff \forall \epsilon > 0, \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) = 0.$$

Here, that means that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = 0$. What can you say about $\mathbb P(|c_n X_n| > \epsilon)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(|c_n||X_n|>\epsilon)\leq\mathbb{P}(|\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|c_n||X_n|>\epsilon)$. Then, let $n\to\infty$, so that we get $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|c_n|\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon)=0$?

Comment: Not quite -- there's no mechanism that lets you "factor" either the $\sup$ or the $c_n$ terms out of the probability operator like that. What happens if you divide the $c_n$ terms across the inequality instead?

Comment: Can we do $\mathbb{P}(|c_n||X_n|>\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon/|c_n|)$ and then send the $\epsilon/|c_n|$ to 0 using boundedness of $c_n$?

Comment: Close -- but you don't have to "send the $\epsilon / |c_n|$ to 0," and you don't even really know that you can -- observe that the $|c_n|$ terms could be close to (or equal to) 0. Use the bound instead: $|c_n X_n| < M |X_n|$, so $\mathbb P(|c_n X_n| > \epsilon) \leq \mathbb P(M |X_n| > \epsilon)$ (why)?, and work with the right-hand expression instead.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Abridged solution using the theorem you wrote.** There is $|c_n| \leq \alpha$ for all $n,$ then the relation $X_{n_{m_k}} \to 0$ (being equivalent to $|X_{n_{m_k}}| \to 0$), implies $0 \leq |c_{n_{m_k}} X_{n_{m_k}}| \leq \alpha |X_{n_{m_k}}| \to 0,$ hence the result. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
C|X_n|\ge |c_n X_n|
$$
for some $C>0$ (if $c_n$ is identically zero the result is trivial) since the sequence $(c_n)$ is bounded. In particular, given $\epsilon>0$,
$$
P(|c_nX_n|>\epsilon)\leq P(C|X_n|>\epsilon)\to 0
$$
since one event is a subset of the other and $X_n\to 0$ in probability.